# Retrieving a portion of a url

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I need your collective wisdom. I am needing to get a portion of a url so that I can pass it as a parameter to make some stuff happen. Here's what I've got:

here is an example of the url "somesite/somepage/johndoe21911", I am needing to get the "21911" so that I can pass it into this:

```
var url = Request.ApplicationPath.Replace("/", "");
Session["agencyId"] = _Apps.GetGehaAgencyData(portion needed goes here);
```

Any direction is greatly appreciated

Comment: I assume this is Asp.Net?  MVC?  Web API?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are many questions about getting a number out of a bigger string

Comment: What exactly does _I am needing to get the "21911"_ mean? In other words, what is the criteria for whatever you want to extract? Is it any numeric from the last portion of the URL, or is it the last five characters, or is it the last five numerical values? You get the drift.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, from the url I am needing to only retrieve the number "21911" and yes this is in C# asp.net, I thought I tagged it. @Sach, any numeric from the last portion. I've come across some stuff on google, but wasn't really sure on how to implement them

Comment: @WayneFerrigno there clearly was not a `asp.net` tag on the question.  I have added it this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your URL looks like an actual URL (with the http:// part) then you could use `Uri` class:

```
private static void Extract()
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://somesite/somepage/johndoe21911");
    string last = uri.Segments.LastOrDefault();
    string numOnly = Regex.Replace(last, "[^0-9 _]", string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(last);
    Console.WriteLine(numOnly);
}
```

If it's exactly like in your example (without the http:// part) then you could do something like this:

```
private static void Extract()
{
    string uri = "http://somesite/somepage/johndoe21911";
    string last = uri.Substring(uri.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    string numOnly = Regex.Replace(last, "[^0-9 _]", string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(last);
    Console.WriteLine(numOnly);
}
```

Above is assuming you want ALL numerics from the last segment of the URL, which is what you've said your requirement is. That is, if your URL were to look like this:

`somesite/somepage/john123doe456"`

This will extract `123456`.

If you want only the last 5 characters, you could simply use `string.Substring()` to extract the last five characters.

If you want numerics *which are at the end of the string* then this would work.

```
private static void Extract()
{
    string uri = "somesite/somepage/john123doe21911";
    string last = uri.Substring(uri.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    string numOnly = Regex.Match(last, @"\d+$").Value;
    Console.WriteLine(last);
    Console.WriteLine(numOnly);
}
```

Oh and saying ***I've come across some stuff on google, but wasn't really sure on how to implement them*** is a very lazy answer. If you Google you can find countless examples of how to do all these things, even on this site itself. Please from next time onward do your research first and *try* yourself first.

Comment: thanks for your time and I will do more due diligence in the future

Comment: Thanks again, I went and made my life easier. The urls will change a bit allowing me to use query strings, I can just use Request.QueryString